# How do I edit Border using editable poly in 3ds Max?

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk, 3ds

[image: Required one]

[image: Alternatively this is what I am getting]

First Image is my Required one.

But Alternatively this is what I am getting in the Second Image.

I don't know which has been changed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the Help Centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply hold shift when you're moving an edge. with doing so you can create a new face.

Comment: Thanks bro. Its working well ( I am just a Begineer)